# use IXML in a Delphi Console Application

Tags: xml, delphi, console-application

With XML-databinding I created a program that reads an xml-file. If I run the GUI-program (Delphi XE7) it works fine. However, I need to make it an Console Application that can be used on the commandline. I can run the program, but once I want to load the xml-file, I get an error: "Interface not supported".

The problem seems to be at:

```
function Loadconversation(const FileName: string): IXMLConversation;
 begin
  Result := LoadXMLDocument(FileName).GetDocBinding('conversation', TXMLConversation,
                                            TargetNamespace) as IXMLConversation;
 end;
```

Thnx.
Arjan

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious difference between GUI app and a console app that leads to behavioural differences like this is that COM is not initialized by default for a console app. For a GUI app, COM is initialized automatically by the framework, but for a console app this does not happen.

So add a call to `CoInitializeEx` at the start of your console application.

```
CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
```

Comment: @whosrdaddy since it's the main thread it doesn't matter much. Put one in if you like. I probably would. The documentation covers that. Presumably the asker still regards MSDN docs as the definitive reference.